# Type ' MySqlConnection' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect a visualbasic .net app to a Mysql database but I'm getting the above error.
I'm targeting .net framework 4.6 and I have installed Connector/NET 8.1.0 and even tried adding refferences to Mysql.Data.Dll using 5.0.0 Alpha but none is working.

The line giving errors is

```
      Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
```

If I change the line to

```
         Dim MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection()
```

and make the connection as follows

```
       Dim Server As String = "localhost"
Dim DbUName As String = "root"
Dim DbUPass As String = ""
Dim DbName As String = "cypos"
```

I get a new error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll` on this line

```
       MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server='" & Server & "';user='" & DbUName & "';password='" & DbUPass & "';database='" & DbName & "'; SSL Mode=None"
```

I have also tried  adding mysql.data.dll from version mysqlconnector version 1.0.0 beta but the error persists. What can I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to install the nuget packet

[image]

Or download https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

and use

```
    Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim myConnectionString As String

    myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;" _
        & "uid=root;" _
        & "pwd=12345;" _
        & "database=test"

    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
        conn.Open()

    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: With this approach, is there any need to add MySql.Data as reference?

Comment: there are two approaches, the second has it included, but you can import MySQL,data, the first  has another Packet for that